# testNG(using Maven)suite on azuredevops,getting "can not find symbol" error at testNG annotations when I ran the Pipeline. working well on local

Tags: java, maven, azure-devops, testng

I have an automation suite developed in Java-Selenium-TestNG. For further ease of jars and dependency I have used Maven. Pom xml runs perfectly fine on my local machine but recently I tried creating AzureDevOps PipeLine and when I ran the pipeline it is not able to find symbols related to TestNG annotations like @Test, @DataProvider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have defined `<scope>test</scope>` for the testng dependency in your pom xml. And the goal of the maven task in your pipeline is compile or package.

As you know the test scope indicates that the dependency will only be provided at test. This might be why the error barks symbols cannot be found.

You can either remove the test scope for testng dependency in pom xml. Or you can move your test classes from `main` directory to `test` directory in your java project.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help. Really Appreciate. I  changed the testng scope to "compile" in my pom. It solved.